# Configure P4merge as my SVN diff tool on OSX

Tags: macos, svn, p4merge

I want to use P4merge as my external diff tool for files in SVN when comparing local to unchanged.   I just spent several hours on this when I should have been coding.

What do I need to do on OSX platform?

Comment: Info at http://semicrazy.wordpress.com/2009/10/08/using-diffmerge-as-your-subversion-external-merge-tool/ might help? Hope it does.

Comment: I am also interested in a short answer to this particular question. So if anybody has a solution, do not hesitate to post a response here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: we should bounty this

Comment: for the record my team now uses git.

Answer (score 4):

This is kind of hacky and only replaces the diff tool, not the merge tool but here it goes:

Create a python script named `p4merge-diff-cmd`:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os.path

P4MERGE = '/Applications/p4merge.app/Contents/Resources/launchp4merge'

p4merge_args= [P4MERGE]
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
  if os.path.exists(arg):
    p4merge_args.append(os.path.abspath(arg))

os.execv(P4MERGE, p4merge_args)
```

and make it executable

```bash
chmod a+x p4merge-diff-cmd
```

Then, in your `~/.subversion/config` file change the line

```
# diff-cmd = diff_program (diff, gdiff, etc.)
```

to

```
diff-cmd = /full/path/to/p4merge-diff-cmd
```

Now `svn diff <file>` should launch `p4merge`.

Answer (score 0):

Picking up on Stefan's answer, you can check what the parameters are that svn passes through and then write the script to pick out the right ones. I'm on bash, so:

```sh
#! /bin/sh
left=$6
right=$7
/Applications/p4merge.app/Contents/MacOS/p4merge $left $right

# Uncomment this to see what svn passes as parameters
# for i in $(seq 1 11)
#   do echo $i : ${!i}
# done
```